# Enter key does not click elements

Tags: jquery, click, element, keypress, enter

The enter key in this script does not click the 'new' button.

Am I missing something here?

The button:

```
<script>
<a class="btn btn-primary"  id="new" href="@Url.Action("New", "New")">New</a>
</script>
```

The script:

```
<script> 
        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $("#new).click();
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: "*Am I missing something here?*" - a syntax error, certainly (`$("#new)` should be `$("#new")`).

Comment: Yes you're missing something. A double quote to be exact.

Comment: Even with the quote it doesn't work?

Comment: If you are expecting the page to navigate to the `href` of the anchor, that may not happen when you trigger a click event programatically

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#new').trigger('click');    
    }
  return false;    
});
```

Missing " and use **'trigger'** function.